# How to read multiple files (images) using gridfs-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

```
 app.get("/allImages", async (req, res) => {
console.log("All Images Api Called");
gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
if (!files || files.length == 0) {
  res.status(404).send("No files exits");
}

let arr = [];

files.map((file) => {
  //Read output to browser
  const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
  arr.push(readstream);
});
res.send(arr)
  });
```

});

I am trying to send the array of read stream so that i can display multiple images at frontend ,  can someone help with this

Answer (score 0):

try using `readStream.pipe(arr)` instead of `arr.push(readStream)`